In VS code facing issue with RUN AND DEBUG for DJANGO
I am running "Run and Debug" in VS Code on a django project. When I do it starts and ends within 2 seconds, without displaying any errors.
Here is the launch.json for reference:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Django",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "autoStartBrowser": false,
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py"
        }
    ]
}

I tried changing the values of each key without any success. I am a beginner at django.

Here are few pointers. Having:
"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py"

in your launch.json indicates that your manage.py is in the root folder, so make sure it is placed in the root of your project, otherwise you can adjust the path in the launch configuration to match your path.
In order to check for any errors and troubleshoot yourself, you can open the VS Code Terminal by navigating to VS Code -> Terminal -> New terminal and make sure you select the Python Debug Console on the right side. Here's what that would look like: 
Also, if you are starting from scratch with Django, there is a nice tutorial provided by VS Code.
